# Django messages framework not displaying messages?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have been using Django messages framework for as long as I can remember but for some reason it does not display any messages on this new app I am building with Django 1.7. Here's my configuration...

#### Settings.py using Sessions Storage

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

#### base.html

```
    {% if messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
```

#### Installed apps tuple

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

#### And views.py that creates the message

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def skills(request, template_name):
    user = request.user
    try:
        skills = Skills.objects.get(user=user)
        credit_options = CreditOptions.objects.filter(credit=user.credit_set.get())
    except Skills.DoesNotExist:
        messages.success(request, "Let's create a skills profile before you begin.")
        return redirect(urlresolvers.reverse('add_skills'))
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'user': user,
        'credit_options': credit_options
    })
```

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
    "Let's create a skills profile before you begin.")
```

Comment: `messages.success()` is a shortcut to your suggestion, regardless, I gave it a shot and still nothing.

Comment: For the downvoters, this is a perfectly valid way of adding a message: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message but I will re-phrase my answer to suit you.

Comment: What's the difference when they both do the same thing?

Comment: @JeffC What are you using for the message engine?

Comment: what do you mean by "message engine?" I am using the built-in Django messages framework.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/messages/#configuring-the-message-engine I know it uses the Fallback storage by default... are you blocking cookies? or have cookies set to https only? You also have to have sessions enabled for the fallback to work.

Comment: I am using Sessions Storage, as noted in my Middleware

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62356/discussion-between-brandon-and-jeffc).